# Expected Value of Unreimbursed Accident Loss

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, actuarial-science

The question goes as follows:
A three person family purchases an auto insurance policy that reimburse accident losses up to a maximum on 4 accidents per year. The joint probability distribution for the number of accidents of this family $(X,Y,Z)$ is given by

$p(x, y, z)=k(x+y+z)$ where $0\leq x,y,z\leq 3$

Suppose that $X$ is not involved in any accident that year, determine the expected number of unreimbursed accident losses during this same year.

I started off this problem by setting up a triple integral with the respective bounds to find $k$.
Given that $x=0$, and the policy has a maximum of 4, unreimbursed losses occur whenever $y+z$ exceeds 4. Then I simply multiplied each possibility of $y+z$ exceeding 4--namely, $(3,2), (2,3)$, and $(3, 3)$-- by its corresponding probability using the pdf given. However I don't seem to be getting this right. What am I missing here?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: This is a discrete probability space, so you should be looking at a sum instead of an integral.  Start by determining the value of $k$.

Comment: Also, from the last paragraph, it sounds like you are computing the probability of at least one unreimbursed accident, which is not what the question asks.